# Remove copy protection in Android

Tags: java, android, security

I want to remove the copy protection of one of my applications at the market. Is necessary to upload a new apk for take effect or is just necessary to uncheck the copy protection checkbox. I dont wanna upload an update if its not necessary

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy protection is obsolete and not so well documentef. Don't try to save a release if you're not sure.

Just ulpload something on the market that is exactly what you eant your users to have.

Bonne nuit,
 Stéphane